# optimized way to calculate compliance in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains task list of persons. followings are columns

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+
| task_id | person_id | task_name         | status     | due_date_time       |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+
|       1 |       111 | walk 20 min daily | INCOMPLETE | 2017-04-13 17:20:23 |
|       2 |       111 | brisk walk 30 min | COMPLETE   | 2017-03-14 20:20:54 |
|       3 |       111 | take medication   | COMPLETE   | 2017-04-20 15:15:23 |
|       4 |       222 | sport             | COMPLETE   | 2017-03-18 14:45:10 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I want to find out monthly compliance in percentage(completed task/total task * 100) of each person like

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| compliance_id | person_id | compliance | month      |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|             1 |       111 |        100 | 2017-03-01 |
|             2 |       111 |         50 | 2017-04-01 |
|             3 |       222 |        100 | 2017-03-01 |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Here person_id 111 has 1 task in month 2017-03-14 and which status is completed, as 1 out of 1 task is completed in march then compliance is 100%

Currently, I am using separate table which stores this compliance but I have to calculate compliance update that table every time the task status is changed

I have tried creating a view also but it's taking too much time to execute view almost 0.5 seconds for 1 million records.

```
CREATE VIEW `person_compliance_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `t`.`person_id`,
        CAST((`t`.`due_date_time` - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(`t`.`due_date_time`) - 1) DAY)
            AS DATE) AS `month`,
        COUNT(`t`.`status`) AS `total_count`,
        COUNT((CASE
            WHEN (`t`.`status` = 'COMPLETE') THEN 1
        END)) AS `completed_count`,
        CAST(((COUNT((CASE
                WHEN (`t`.`status` = 'COMPLETE') THEN 1
            END)) / COUNT(`t`.`status`)) * 100)
            AS DECIMAL (10 , 2 )) AS `compliance`
    FROM
        `task` `t`
    WHERE
        ((`t`.`isDeleted` = 0)
            AND (`t`.`due_date_time` < NOW())
    GROUP BY `t`.`person_id` , EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `t`.`due_date_time`)
```

Is there any optimized way to do it?

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for suggestion. sample data is updated. please check

Comment: Can you also show us the code you wrote for the view?

Comment: @SteveLovell added the view

Comment: That looks pretty clean. A few suggestions: consider making the `group by` agree with the `month`. One of those may be more efficient than the other, so if either is acceptable in the output, try both ways. Hopefully MySQL will find it then has less to do. You could even have Month as a column in the table and have a trigger calculate it on insert/update of a new due date. That way you could get rid of the need to calculate that entirely. I'm no expert on indexes, but you might want to think about indexes on `person_id` and `due_date_time` (or better still that extra `month` column).

Comment: @SteveLovell thanks for the suggestion. But I am still not confident with view,  how much can it be optimized. because as data will increase I am scared of performance. I have another solution but dont know it is good idea or not. creating the output table i.e compliance. and update it using triggers everytime status of task is changed or new task is added. But dont dont know it is possible with trigger or not

Comment: I agree. If 0.5s is a problem (it seems fairly quick to me, but if that 0.5 sec is for an end-user, that's a different issue). You said your "old" method was updating a table. Did you do that manually, on a schedule, or via triggers?

Comment: I was updating old table via java code. my code was finding compliance dynamically and update into table. But main problem was if I update status in table manually(on the request of customer) then the compliance table was not updating. that's why I was in the search of another way

Answer (score 1):

The first question to consider is whether the view can be optimized to give the required performance. This may mean making some changes to the underlying tables and data structure. For example, you might want indexes and you should check query plans to see where they would be most effective.

Other possible changes which would improve efficiency include adding an extra column "year_month" to the base table, which you could populate via a trigger. Another possibility would be to move all the deleted tasks to an 'archive' table to give the view less data to search through.

Whatever you do, a view will always perform worse than a table (assuming the table has relevant indexes). So depending on your needs you may find you need to use a table. That doesn't mean you should junk your view entirely. For example, if a daily refresh of your table is sufficient, you could use your view to help:

```
truncate table compliance;
insert into compliance select * from compliance_view;
```

Truncate is more efficient than delete, but you can't use a rollback, so you might prefer to use delete and top-and-tail with `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;`. I've never created scheduled jobs in MySQL, but if you need help, this looks like a good starting point: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-event.html)

If daily isn't often enough, you could schedule this to run more often than daily, but better options will be triggers and/or "partial refreshes" (my term, I've no idea if there is a technical term for the idea.

A perfectly written trigger would spot any relevant insert/update/delete and then insert/update/delete the related records in the compliance table. The logic is a little daunting, and I won't attempt it here. An easier option would be a "partial refresh" on called within a trigger. The trigger would spot user targetted by the change, delete only the records from `compliance` which are related to that user and then insert from your `compliance_view` the records relating to that user. You should be able to put that into a stored procedure which is called by the trigger.

### Update expanding on the options (if a view just won't do):

**Option 1: Daily full (or more frequent) refresh via a schedule**

You'd want code like this executed (at least) daily.

```
truncate table compliance;
insert into compliance select * from compliance_view;
```

**Option 2: Partial refresh via trigger**

I don't work with triggers often, so can't recall syntax, but the logic should be as follows (not actual code, just pseudo-code)

```
AFTER INSERT -- you may need one for each of INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE
FOR EACH ROW -- or if there are multiple rows and you can trigger only on the last one to be changed, that would be better

DELETE FROM compliance
WHERE person_id = INSERTED.person_id

INSERT INTO compliance select * from compliance_view where person_id = INSERTED.person_id

END
```

**Option 3: Smart update via trigger**

This would be similar to option 2, but instead of deleting all the rows from compliance that relate to the relevant person_id and creating them from scratch, you'd work out which ones to update, and update them and whether any should be added / deleted. The logic is a little involved, and I'm not not going to attempt it here.

Personally, I'd be most tempted by Option 2, but you'd need to combine it with option 1, since the data goes stale due to the use of `now()`.

Comment: You mean putting above query in trigger? `truncate table compliance;
insert into table compliance select * from compliance_view;`

Comment: My response got a bit long ... reworking into an update to my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar way of writing the same thing...

Views are of very limited benefit in MySQL, and I think should generally be avoided.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,person_id INT NOT NULL
,task_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,status ENUM('INCOMPLETE','COMPLETE') NOT NULL
,due_date_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,111,'walk 20 min daily','INCOMPLETE','2017-04-13 17:20:23'),
(2,111,'brisk walk 30 min','COMPLETE','2017-03-14 20:20:54'),
(3,111,'take medication','COMPLETE','2017-04-20 15:15:23'),
(4,222,'sport','COMPLETE','2017-03-18 14:45:10');

SELECT person_id
     , DATE_FORMAT(due_date_time,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
     , SUM(status = 'complete')/COUNT(*) x
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY person_id
     , yearmonth;

person_id yearmonth x
      111 2017-03   1.0
      111 2017-04   0.5
      222 2017-03   1.0
```

Comment: data in table 'task' can be changed. I need compliance calculation on the current status

Comment: I don't understand that comment, and cannot see how it has any bearing on the above.

Comment: Well the code is virtually the same as that by OP, but missing the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @SteveLovell Yes, because the data in the WHERE clause is not part of the given data set.